# Spring - how to @Autowired jpa repository if mock is working fine

Tags: spring, testing

I'm writing tests for my Controller class. I have configuration class which looks like this :

```
@Configuration
@Import(RoomRepository.class)
public class TestConfig {
@MockBean
RoomRepository roomRepository;

@Bean
ReservationService reservationService() {
    return new ReservationService(roomRepository);
}
```

}

In controller test class I'm injecting config class :

```
@WebMvcTest(ReservationController.class)
@Import({TestConfig.class})
class ReservationControllerTest { ... }
```

Everything works well except one thing. I need "real" room repository - not mock. When I try to @Autowired that repository I'm receiving an error that it's interface, not class (which is quite obvious). How can I initialize working instance of RoomRepository ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```html
private RoomRepository roomRepository;

@Autowired
public YourClassName(RoomRepository roomRepository){
this.roomRepository = roomRepository
}
```